# what happens when two update for same record comes in one file while loading in DB using INFORMATICA

Tags: etl, informatica

Suppose I Have a table xyz:

### id    name    add    city    act_flg    start_dtm    end_dtm

1    amit    abc,z  pune       Y        21012018      null

and this table is loaded from a file Using Informatica using SCD2.

suppose there is one file that contains two record with id=2
ie. 2    vipul    abc,z    mumbai
    2    vipul    asdf     bangalore

so who will this be loaded into db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how your doing the SCD type 2. If you are using a look-up with Static cache , both records will be added end date as null

Best case in this scenario is to use a dynamic lookup cache and read your source data in such a way that latest record is read last. This will ensure one record is expired with end date and only one active record( ie end date is null) exists per id.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm 1 of 2 possibilities depending on what you mean... if you mean that you're pulling data from different source systems which sometimes have the same ids on those systems then its easy... just stamp both the natural key (i.e. the id) and a source system value on the dimension column along with the arbitrary surrogate key which is unique to your target table... (this is a datawarehousing basic so read kimball).

If you mean that you are somehow tracing realtime changes in the single record in the source system and writing these changes to the input files of your etl job then you need to agree with your client whether they're happy for you to aggregate them based on the timestamp of the change and just pick the most recent one or to create 2 records, one with its expiry datetime set and the other still open (which is the standard scd approach... again read kimball).